# How is the amount of memory in stack area determined at compile time only?

Tags: c

Activation records are created in stack. These are created and destroyed during program run- that is stack area changes its size during program run.

Even though memory in stack area is created during run time- the amount of memory (activation record size) is determined at compile time.

I am not getting this concept that when memory in stack area is created during run time then how can the size of activation record determined at compile time ?

Comment: The amount of stack is usually fixed for a given OS/operating environment. If you overflow the stack with the records your program crashes.

Comment: Each time a function is called, it needs some stack space, so that space is allocated — the activation record.  It is known at compile time how big the activation record is for a given procedure (more or less; variable length arrays complicate things), but it isn't known how much space will be needed in total because the sequence of function calls isn't known — especially with recursion and the like.

Comment: The size is determined by the local variables that the function needs to use simultaneously. That quantity can be determined when you compile the function. The only thing that's dynamic is *where* to put that storage.

Comment: But in general there may be many functions which are defined but we call only say  3 functions so then will the stack size be determined from the size of these 3 functions only or it is fixed by OS for all kinds of programs

Comment: Technically _sometimes_ in certain environments you can limit the stack size for a given program, but in general a program starts with a limited amount of stack which doesn't grow as program runs and uses it.

Comment: Generally speaking, the stack area *does not* change in size during a program run.  That's why you can have a stack overflow without exhausting a machine's memory.  What changes at run time is how much of the stack is in use, vs. how much is available, unused.

Comment: Stack is used only for a given _call sequence_. So if you have 100500 functions defined, but only call a couple and they in turn don't call other functions, then only certain amount stack required to run those particular functions is used.

Comment: Not sure I get the question. If if is about how compiler can determine required stack size - then it can't, there are just some predefined sizes compilers (or more like it, linkers) use and hope it is enough. If it is about why stack growing isn't implemented, then I guess noone really seen much need for that, specially if this operation wouldn't be free.

Comment: Stack size per thread is fixed, and this is normally set with a linker parameter or it has a default value.

Comment: C does not specify how a stack is allocated, fixed or dynamic or even that it exists! It is OS specific.  Post the OS of interest to get good answers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "It is known at compile time how big the activation record is for a given procedure" I know this is true, but I never understood why this is - where should I start looking if I want to dig into this more? I have been studying the dragon compilers book but failed to come to an understanding from what I read so far.

Answer (score 2):

When the OS starts a process it allocates a fixed amount of space for that process t use as a stack.  Memory is not created or destroyed when functions start or end.  It is borrowed from the top of the whatever is unused on the stack.

When a function is called it grabs a chuck of that stack space ( at the top of stack ) that it will use itself ( for variable ).  The compiler can scan a function and calculate all that in advance, as it does not need to allow for function calls made with each function - they are all treated independently.

As a function exists it releases that stack space ( simply adjusts the stack pointer back to what it was ) and returns to the caller.

As every function called does it's own reserve and free of space from the top of stack, the compiler does not need to allow for stack space used by functions called within other functions.  Each function always works from the existing top of the stack ( where the free space is ).

Malloc() uses the heap memory, which is separate from the stack.  Only local variables use the stack.  There is an unsafe function called alloca() that also uses the stack, but it is not normally used as it cannot be relied on to return a valid pointer.

Comment: This answer may relate to some OS's but not all.  Suggest listing the OS you are writing about.

Comment: This is a general outline for call frame stack use.  It was intended to clarify what I think is confusing the poster, which I think related to functions calling functions.  It was not intended as a definitive description of stack usage in any particular OS.  That would really confuse the OP and loose sight of the issue.  If you feel the need to get into such detail you are free to answer more fully yourself, after all.

Comment: We generally say that the stack grows downwards while the heap grows upwards so then how can the stack size remain fixed initially only during compile time , still confused ,please clarify this point

Comment: I think you are fixating on compile time a bit here.  The stack size on some systems can change, all the compiler does is follow the specification for how to use the stack when generating code.  Exactly what that entails is system specific.  The heap and the stack should not generally be thought of as connected.  A heap does not necessarily grow.  Parts of the heap are allocated ( borrowed ) by the app as it malloc()s, but whether the heap is allowed to grow or not is dependent on the OS.